# NavigationView with multiple group hide & show group based on Condition

Tags: android, navigationview, android-support-design, android-navigationview

I have `NavigationView` with multiple Groups which is based on some condition I  need to hide & show the group. How I can achieve this.

My Sample `NavigationView` menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/grp_employee"
        >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
            android:title="@string/app_name" />

.......
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/grp_admin"
        >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/admin_help"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
            android:title="@string/app_name" />

.......
</group>

<group> ... </group>

</menu>
```

This is the my NavigationView file. I just want to **show only one group view at a time hide all others group**.

Comment: why negative vote explain whats wrong. If you guys unable to answer why put a negative vote

Comment: For those who get here now, I would like to add that you can also set the group's visibility in the xml ( android:visible="false ). That makes it the default when you launch the application. Then you can alter it programmatically when you have to

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you can use [`Menu.setGroupVisible (int group, boolean visible)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#setGroupVisible(int,%20boolean)) to hide or show menu group.

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_id,false);//to hide
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_id,true);//to show
```

Comment: hello ,but programatically i need to check is that group_id is visible or not ,so how can i? is thare any idea

Comment: @sunita not sure, but try this method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#hasVisibleItems()

Comment: I have tried several methods, but this one works the most and simple

Answer (score 0):

You can check visibility for one of the items in group, and the result is equal to group visibility.
For example, check `admin_help` visibility by this line:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.admin_help).isVisible()
```

and the results is same to check `grp_admin` visibility