# How To Change NavigationView Menu Programmatically

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I have a `navigationView` with  a `headerLayout` and also `menu` attach to it. I didn't used any library for this one.
I'm trying to achieved the same effect with google `navigationView` but the difference is that, not changing account but to view extra's/hidden command (for the admin side if the user is admin).

**How do I add/inflate this thing?** I have two `menu's`. I attempt to do this yet, what I get is, it duplicate itself. Causing the `navigationView` to have the same icons and name's. I created two methods, calling them when the image button is clicked.

Here's my code: **MainActivity.java**

```
public void changeNavigationDrawer(){

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    mNavigationView.getMenu();
    mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            switch (id){

                //Nav list no 1 is User Profile
                //Nav list no 2
                case R.id.my_friends:
                    Intent intent_friends = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CommunityFriendsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent_friends);
                    finish();
                    break;

                //Nav list no 3
                case R.id.my_feeds:
                    //BY DEFAULT YOU'RE in the FEEDS SECTION
                    break; }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

The other method in the same file:

```
public void adminNavigationDrawer(){
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation_drawer_admin);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

[image: ImageHeader]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer.

The material drawer library is easy, flexible(absolutely NO limits) and you can take advantage predefined classes.

You can set up the Material Drawer in few minutes using this library.

or If you want to do it using by your own. You can create two groups and perform hide/show on each group on clicking arrow button in your header view.

// Edited

for hiding and showing the group

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37202286/5028508

Comment: I already downloaded that one, and I don't want to use it. To save file size. But I will try the hide and show approach. I will double check if that function is there.

Comment: I'm trying to implement that one :)

Comment: I already found out how to change the menu programmatically by - NavigationView.getMenu().clear();

Comment: i also did the same when i didn't use material drawer.

Comment: But i thought hiding and showing would be much cleaner solution than adding or removing and setting listeners

Comment: From that approach I also used the equivalent toggle button if statement. So when it clear the menu I re-inflate the other one. The reGroup, reGroupRemove didn't work for me. :(